# Can someone explain why this statement is false?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Can someone explain why this statement is false?

**Although 2000 years of efforts to prove the parallel postulate as a theorem in neutral geometry have been unsuccessful, it is still possible that someday some genius will succeed in proving it.**

Comment: This is the [second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261669/parallel-postulate) question you ask in rapid sequence, without providing any context (where does the quote come from?) or any of your own thoughts (why do you think it's false?). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

We have a model of hyperbolic geometry where the parallel postulate is false.  We have a model of Euclidean geometry where the parallel postulate is true.  Both extend the axioms of hyperbolic geometry.  If the axioms of neutral geometry are inconsistent, anything is provable, so you could prove the parallel postulate.  Otherwise, we have shown that the axioms of neutral geometry are consistent with both, so the parallel postulate cannot be proven.

Comment: could you please explain what neutral geometry means? and how this shows that the parallel postulate is unprovable?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_geometry) calls it absolute geometry but acknowledges the synonym.  It is Euclidean geometry without the parallel postulate.

Comment: oh ok. I didn't see that OP used the term though

Comment: @gebra:  We have a set of axioms (absolute geometry) and another proposed axiom (parallel postulate).  If we can make two models, both in absolute geometry, one of which makes the parallel postulate true and one which makes it false, we can be confident that the parallel postulate is not decidable by the other axioms.

Comment: really, that very conterintuitive